# Custom post type not showing in the admin bar

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created custom post types in the mu_plugins folder. But it's not showing up in the admin menu bar.
I tried pasting the code in functions.php, but no change.
I have used the register_post_type function to create the new post types.
See code below

```
 <?php
function odays_post_types()
{
  register_post_type('hotels', array(
    'capability_type' => 'hotels',
    'map_meta_cap' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'hotels'),
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields'),
    'has_archive' => true,
    'public' => false,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => 'Hotels',
      'add_new_item' => 'Add New Hotel',
      'edit_item' => 'Edit Hotel',
      'all_items' => 'All Hotels',
      'singular_name' => 'Hotel'
    ),
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-multisite'
  ));
  register_post_type('clinic', array(
    'capability_type' => 'clinic',
    'map_meta_cap' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'clinic'),
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields'),
    'public' => true,
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => 'Clinics',
      'add_new_item' => 'Create New Clinic',
      'edit_item' => 'Edit Clinic',
      'all_items' => 'All Clinics',
      'singular_name' => 'Clinic'
    ),
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-plus-alt'
  ));
  register_post_type('agent', array(
    'capability_type' => 'agent',
    'map_meta_cap' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'agent'),
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'public' => true,
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => 'Agents',
      'add_new_item' => 'Create New Agent',
      'edit_item' => 'Edit Agent',
      'all_items' => 'All Agents',
      'singular_name' => 'Agent'
    ),
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-plus-alt'
  ));
}
add_action('init', 'odays_post_types');
 ?>
```

Please help

Comment: It's been a long time since I've used WP. Don't you have to install the plugin to make it appear in the menu?

Comment: Check the order that mu plugins are loaded to ensure that the init hook hasn't already fired. Perhaps if it did you could try 'after_theme_setup'. Please also confirm that the code there is being run.

Comment: According to the chart here (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71406/is-there-a-flowchart-for-wordpress-loading-sequence), my comment is not correct (mu plugins are long before init). It could be another weird issue with timing. Also, ensure the show_ui argument default to true, if not, set it to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better and easy way of creating a custom post type you can use a plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/ and after creating a post type

And after creating custom post type you can remove plugin if you want and you can get code like this just copy this code and past in function.php it will work fine without plugin also.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove

```
'capability_type' => 'hotels',
'capability_type' => 'clinic',
'capability_type' => 'agent',
```

Comment: What will happen in the background when I remove these?

Answer (score -1):

You can copy and paste this code within your functions.php file.

// Register Custom Post Type clinic
function create_clinic_cpt() {

```
$labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'clinic', 'Post Type General Name', 'textdomain' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'clinic', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'textdomain' ),
    'menu_name' => _x( 'clinic', 'Admin Menu text', 'textdomain' ),
    'name_admin_bar' => _x( 'clinic', 'Add New on Toolbar', 'textdomain' ),
    'archives' => __( 'clinic Archives', 'textdomain' ),
    'attributes' => __( 'clinic Attributes', 'textdomain' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent clinic:', 'textdomain' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All clinic', 'textdomain' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New clinic', 'textdomain' ),
    'add_new' => __( 'Add New', 'textdomain' ),
    'new_item' => __( 'New clinic', 'textdomain' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit clinic', 'textdomain' ),
    'update_item' => __( 'Update clinic', 'textdomain' ),
    'view_item' => __( 'View clinic', 'textdomain' ),
    'view_items' => __( 'View clinic', 'textdomain' ),
    'search_items' => __( 'Search clinic', 'textdomain' ),
    'not_found' => __( 'Not found', 'textdomain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'textdomain' ),
    'featured_image' => __( 'Featured Image', 'textdomain' ),
    'set_featured_image' => __( 'Set featured image', 'textdomain' ),
    'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'textdomain' ),
    'use_featured_image' => __( 'Use as featured image', 'textdomain' ),
    'insert_into_item' => __( 'Insert into clinic', 'textdomain' ),
    'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this clinic', 'textdomain' ),
    'items_list' => __( 'clinic list', 'textdomain' ),
    'items_list_navigation' => __( 'clinic list navigation', 'textdomain' ),
    'filter_items_list' => __( 'Filter clinic list', 'textdomain' ),
);
$args = array(
    'label' => __( 'clinic', 'textdomain' ),
    'description' => __( '', 'textdomain' ),
    'labels' => $labels,
    'menu_icon' => '',
    'supports' => array(),
    'taxonomies' => array(),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
);
register_post_type( 'clinic', $args );

  }
 add_action( 'init', 'create_clinic_cpt', 0 );
```